# UltraESB Start Up Error

Tags: java, macos, esb, ultraesb, adroitlogic

I'm running Mac OSX and have installed [UltraESB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraESB). When I try to run it I get the following error:

```
adding os/x equivalent of tools.jar
Starting AdroitLogic UltraESB ... Using JAVA_HOME  :
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home Using
ULTRA_HOME: /opt/ultraesb-2.2.0 log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call
failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: logs/ultraesb.log (Permission
denied)
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

I gave the folder read, write and execute permissions.

Comment: It sucks that `chmod 777` is the solution to everything. But really this helped me in a pinch; thanks!